# PHP CodeIigniter - PDF generator

Tags: php, pdf-generation

Need help in PDF generation because I am doing a project with PHP CodeIgniter.

I need to convert some HTML documents (of min 10 pages) into PDF.

I heard that wkhtmltopdf is good compared to others.

But how to incorporate it into the web pages, since I see it as command line converter. 
Any example would be more helpful or any suggestion for a good PDF generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PHP class built on top of wkhtmltopdf: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp